# Using regex with sets in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a set in Java with different strings, such as '+Cat', '+Dog', etc. I also have a string as shown below.

```
animals = '+Cat|+Dog|+Goat'
```

Basically, if the set contains any of the animals listed in animals, I want to return false. How would I go about doing this? I am not sure if you can use regex with contains. Furthermore the fact that I have the `+` in my string complicates regex.

Comment: You can split `animals` by `|` to `List` and the check if your strings are in this list

Answer (score 6):

```
public boolean containCheck(Set<String> newset) {
    String animals = "+Cat|+Dog|+Goat";
    for (String op : animals.split("\\|")) {
        if (newset.contains(op)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string in array and use a for loop to check it the set contains any element presents in the array.

```
public Boolean isContaining(String animals, Set<String> sets ) {
    for (String s : animals.split("\\|")) {
        for (String set : sets) {
            if (s.equals(set)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```